# How do similar writes give different results in Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can someone please explain why, while testing Firebase security rules the below two simulated writes which I think are essentially the same give different results?

***Write1***

**Simulator location:**  /users/id123/state
**Simulator data(JSON):** {"data":"example}

---

***Write2***

**Simulator location:**  /users/id123/
**Simulator data(JSON):** {"state":{"data":"example}}

---

Write 1 denies the wright at the "state":, ".write" line in the below rules.

Write 2 skips the "state":, ".write" line altogether.

*This is an issue because I am updating multiple paths in one JSON update and its skipping rules.*

Does anyone know why?

```
{  
    "rules":{  
        "users":{  
            "$userId":{  
                "state":{  
                    ".write":false,
                    ".read":false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: None of your rules give anyone permission to write anywhere in the database. All writes from regular users should fail with these rules, regardless of the location they write to. Writes from an administrative user will always succeed, because their access bypasses the rules. How are you testing the writes? Can you give me the minimal steps with which I can reproduce what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is for denying writes at all the locations at or deeper under your state node.

So any writes at

```
/Users/uid/state
```

And any rules under states

```
/Users/uid/state/foo/bar
```

Will be denied.

But if you write the data to

```
/Users/uid
```

The rule doesn't apply as it's not at or under the state node, it's a shallower node which doesn't have any rules stated. You can put your rules at

```
{  
"rules":{  
    "users":{  
        "$userId":{  

                  ".write":false,
                  ".read":false

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rules above will prevent writes for all the paths under your uid node. Also if you are using the REST api or the admin api, all rules will get bypassed

The REST API and the ADMIN API will both need a service account key file that only you will have. Thus they are secure. They'll give you admin access and will always bypass all security rules at all locations.

Comment: "Also if you are using the REST api or the admin api, all rules will get bypassed" I don't know about the admin API but don't you need the secret key if you want to do that with the REST API?

Comment: Yea you do need a secret key. I'm just saying if you have that and you are using the rest api, it'll bypass all the rules.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to include that. Right now someone can think that simply using the Admin or REST API is enough to bypass all rules.

Comment: Lol... Yea fair point, if they don't know about it, it'll convey the wrong message :D

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave you are writing to different locations and firebase security will first look at the location you are writing at to check the rules.

***Write2***

**Simulator location:**  /users/id123/
**Simulator data(JSON):** {"state":{"data":"example}}

Here you are writing to  `/users/id123/` and firebase will check that location for a write rule which in you case isn't present so it will use the default `".write":false`.

For writing your rules you have to make sure to set them at the correct level.

Take a look at [firebase security authorization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization) (who can read/read) and also [validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-validation) (what can be written).

Comment: So the write always uses security rules at the location and doesn't refer to the nested JSON for the full path? So for example, if you have the location set as the root and the JSON contains two multipath updates as below then the rules at root are used and not at the paths in the JSON for eg : 

{  
    "users/id123/state/":{  
        "data":"example"
    },
    "settings/id123":{  
        "activated":"yes"
    }
}

Comment: @LukeStanyer What exactly are you asking about multipath updates?